# Using WritePixels when using a writeable bitmap from a intptr to create a bitmap.

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, scanning

Im currently trying to use writeablebitmap to take a `IntPtr` of a scan of images and turn each one into a `Bitmap`. Im wanting to use writeablebitmap because im having an issue with standard gdi
[GDI+ System.Drawing.Bitmap gives error Parameter is not valid intermittently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130790/gdi-system-drawing-bitmap-gives-error-parameter-is-not-valid-intermittently)

There is a method on a `WriteableBitmap` that called `WritePixels`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346817.aspx

Im not sure what I set for the buffer and the stride every example I find it shows the stride as 0 although that throws an error. When I set the stride to 5 the image appear black. I know this may not be the most efficient code but any help would be appreciated.

```
//create bitmap header
bmi = new BITMAPINFOHEADER();

//create initial rectangle
Int32Rect rect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);

//create duplicate intptr to use while in global lock
dibhand = dibhandp;
bmpptr = GlobalLock(dibhand);

//get the pixel sizes
pixptr = GetPixelInfo(bmpptr);

//create writeable bitmap
var wbitm = new WriteableBitmap(bmprect.Width, bmprect.Height, 96.0, 96.0, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);

//draw the image
wbitm.WritePixels(rect, dibhandp, 10, 0);

//convert the writeable bitmap to bitmap
var stream = new MemoryStream();

var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(wbitm));
encoder.Save(stream);

byte[] buffer = stream.GetBuffer();
var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(new MemoryStream(buffer));

GlobalUnlock(dibhand);
GlobalFree(dibhand);
GlobalFree(dibhandp);
GlobalFree(bmpptr);
dibhand = IntPtr.Zero;

return bitmap;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An efficient way to work on Bitmaps in C# is to pass temporarily in unsafe mode (I know I don't answer the question exactly but I think the OP did not manage to use Bitmap, so this could be a solution anyway). You just have to lock bits and you're done:

```
unsafe private void GaussianFilter()
{
    // Working images
    using (Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(width, height))
    {
        // Lock bits for performance reason
        BitmapData newImageData = newImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, newImage.Width,
            newImage.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        byte* pointer = (byte*)newImageData.Scan0;
        int offset = newImageData.Stride - newImageData.Width * 4;

        // Compute gaussian filter on temp image
        for (int j = 0; j < InputData.Height - 1; ++j)
        {
            for (int 0 = 1; i < InputData.Width - 1; ++i)
            {
                // You browse 4 bytes per 4 bytes
                // The 4 bytes are: B G R A
                byte blue = pointer[0];
                byte green = pointer[1];
                byte red = pointer[2];
                byte alpha = pointer[3];

                // Your business here by setting pointer[i] = ...
                // If you don't use alpha don't forget to set it to 255 else your whole image will be black !!

                // Go to next pixels
                pointer += 4;
            }
            // Go to next line: do not forget pixel at last and first column
            pointer += offset;
        }


        // Unlock image
        newImage.UnlockBits(newImageData);
        newImage.Save("D:\temp\OCR_gray_gaussian.tif");
    }
}
```

This is really much more efficient than `SetPixel(i, j)`, you just have to be careful about pointer limits (and not forget to unlock data when you're done).

Now to answer your question about stride: the stride is the length in bytes of a line, it is a multiple of 4. In my exemple I use the format `Format32bppArgb` which uses 4 bytes per pixel (R, G, B and alpha), so `newImageData.Stride` and `newImageData.Width * 4` are always the same. I use the offset in my loops only to show where it would be necessary.

But if you use another format, for instance `Format24bppRgb` which uses 3 bytes per pixel (R, G and B only), then there may be an offset between stride and width. For an image 10 * 10 pixels in this format, you will have a stride of 10 * 3 = 30, + 2 to reach nearest multiple of 4, i.e. 32.