# Create IntPtr for specified image data

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing

(I'm not even sure how to ask this in an correct way, sorry. My image processing skills are basically non existent.)

I have a function in a library (namely `bool CLNUIDevice.GetCameraColorFrameRGB32(...)` from  CL.NUI to read Kinect data) that I have to pass an `IntPtr data` as an argument. The resulting image data will end up in this `data`.

I want to do some image processing with that data and display it on screen (in a `PictureBox`, I guess).

When I pass a variable set to `IntPtr.Zero` it stays `0`. As I understand it, I have to initialize the `data` correctly. My image is 640x480 pixels and judging from the examples it should have `PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb`

**How do I have to initialize the `IntPtr` for a 640x480 pixel bitmap that seems to have 32 bits per pixel?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14.aspx) object, using your width/height/bpp and the image data pointer passed in through the constructor.

You can then display that bitmap anyway you choose.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var bmp = new Bitmap(640, 480, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bd = null;
        try {
            bd = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
            var pointer = bd.Scan0;
            // Make the call, passing *pointer*
            //...
        }
        finally {
            if (bd != null) bmp.UnlockBits(bd);
        }
        // Do something with <bmp>
        //...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping this link will helps you [Using WritePixels when using a writeable bitmap from a intptr to create a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731036/using-writepixels-when-using-a-writeable-bitmap-from-a-intptr-to-create-a-bitmap)

you can change this depends upon  your requirement...